# mongodb 3.2.18 use slice in pipeline Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$slice'

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, slice, pipeline

In the document of mongodb, "$slice" was introduced in version 3.2. However, after upgrading my mongodb to 3.2, I still get this error. And I also check the db.version() and mongo --version, both of them are 3.2.18.

**EDIT** from the comments aggregate pipeline

```
db.test.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match : {"keya" : val}, {$slice : ["$mylist", 2] }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your code.

Comment: the code just like this : db.test.aggregate([{$match : {"keya" : vala}}, {$slice : ["mylist", 2]}])

Comment: sorry, the code just like this : db.test.aggregate([{$match : {"keya" : vala}}, {$slice : ["$mylist", 2]}])

Comment: You can use regular find query. Something like `db.test.find( { keya: val }, { keya:1, mylist: {$slice: 2} } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html) cannot be used as a top level operator in aggregation pipeline but only as a part of $project. Please not that in MongoDB docs it is a part of `Aggregation Pipeline Operators` and not `Aggregation Pipeline Stages`.

Try following code:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match : {"keya" : vala}}, 
    { $project: { keya: 1, myList: { $slice: [ "$myList", 2 ] } } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, it also reminds me to distinguish the pipeline operators and pipeline stages.